# Identifying Main and Subordinate clauses

Tags: syntactic-analysis, dependent-clause, independent-clauses

In the sentence:

> His family and professional life have made him uniquely able to write novels with a family setting which can absorb the conflict between past and present, tradition and novelty, good and evil, common beliefs and the idea of the modern family today.

I am having trouble identifying the main and subordinate clauses. I suspect that that there’s 1 subordinate clause (adjective clause “which can absorb...) but I am not sure.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

> [*His family and professional life have made him uniquely able* [*to write*
> *novels with a family setting* [*which can absorb the conflict between*
> *past and present, tradition and novelty, good and evil, common beliefs*
> *and the idea of the modern family today*]]]

In the simplest analysis, there is one main clause (the sentence as a whole) and two subordinate clauses, i.e. the infinitival clause “to write novels …”, and the relative clause “which can absorb …”. Brackets surround the clauses.

In more advanced grammar, there are two further subordinate clauses, i.e. the "made him uniquely ..." clause, which is complement of "have", and the "absorb the conflict ..." clause, which is complement of "can".

[*His family and professional life have* [*made him uniquely able* [*to write novels with a family setting* [*which can* [*absorb the conflict between past and present, tradition and novelty, good and evil, common beliefs and the idea of the modern family today*]]]]].

Comment: You've mentioned in one comment that _infinitival clauses are non-finite and all non- finite clauses are subordinate._ So, in the sentence _To write The Great American Novel is my aim_, there is one main clause (the whole sentence) and one subordinate clause (the infinitival clause _To write TGAN..._), right? One more thing: In the past I remember you once corrected me over my calling an adjective clause a relative clause, or the other way round. Here you didn't bother to point out this thing. Or are they one and the same thing here?@BillJ

Comment: Yes, the infinitival _To write The Great American Novel_ is a non-finite subordinate clause functioning as subject of the sentence. So we have a main clause, which is the sentence as a whole and whose verb is "is", and one sub clause. Relative clause is the correct term -- much better than adjective clause. I should have pointed that out! The classification of finite subordinate clauses is based on their internal structure, not on spurious analogies with the parts of speech.

Comment: Thank you very much, @BillJ! :)

Comment: Is the rationale the same when identifying the main and subordinate clauses in such sentences as contain no _non-finite_ elements? I mean should one treat the whole sentence _Peter felt that he had been cheated_ or just _Peter felt_ as the main clause? The definition of a clause is still satisfied if one chooses to call only _Peter felt_ as the main clause (it contains both subject and predicate.) The subordinate clause is the same of course (_that he had been cheated._) Sorry for not asking this as a separate question @BillJ

Comment: I guess I should be able to answer this myself. As per the rule you taught— _As many clauses as verbs— means  Peter felt_ is a separate clause. So, One main clause and two dependent clauses, right?

Comment: No: In _Peter felt that he had been cheated_ the whole sentence is the main clause. "Peter felt" is not a clause, but just part of one. The clause "that he had been cheated" is embedded inside the main clause (usually called the matrix clause). Importantly, the _that_ clause is complement of the verb "felt" and thus is inseparable from it.

Comment: Thank you, BillJ! Got it. So, this _object of a transitive verb_ concept doesn't have much place in modern grammar and it's proper to replace it with _complement of a verb_?

Comment: @user405662 It does, but objects are NPs, not clauses. Would it be helpful if I drew a tree diagram of your "Peter" example.

Comment: @user405662 I've gone ahead and posted a tree diagram of your "Peter" example.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're referring to *some specific novels with a family setting*, you need to put a comma before *which* in your sentence (meaning *all the novels with a family setting* fit the description provided by the following adjectival clause.)  Furthermore, just to make sure it's the novels (*and not the family setting*) the clause is modifying, it would perhaps be better to italicize the part *novels with a family setting.*

As regards the clause identification, you have got that right: the clause leading up to *novels with a family setting* is independent, and the clause following it is dependent.

Comment: Thank you! As I’ve mentioned, I was also thinking that maybe the “to write novels with a family setting” clause could also be a noun clause functioning as adjective complement of “able”. Would that also be correct?

Comment: In the simplest analysis, there is one main clause (the sentence as a whole) and two subordinate clauses, i.e. the infinitival “to write …” clause and the relative clause “which can absorb …”

Comment: [His family and professional life have made him uniquely able [to write novels with a family setting [which can absorb the conflict between past and present, tradition and novelty, good and evil, common beliefs and the idea of the modern family today]]]. Brackets surround the clauses.

Comment: Very useful comments as always. Many thanks, @BillJ!

Comment: Note also the more advanced analysis, as shown in my answer.

Comment: One main clause: "His family and professional life have made him uniquely able to write novels with a family setting"; One subordinate clause: "...which can absorb the conflict between past and present, tradition and novelty, good and evil, common beliefs and the idea of the modern family today." How's "to write" a clause?  It is an infinitive phrase; it doesn't have subject & predicate.

Comment: _able_ itself is the object complement describing the object of the transitive verb— _him._ _to write novels with a family setting_ is the gerundial infinitive phrase acting as an adverb and modifying _able._ Note, all this is as per traditional grammatical analysis. But I don't think, either traditional or modern approach, would treat the part _to write novels with a family setting_ as a prepositional phrase because _to_ isn't a preposition there. @Jananlov

Answer (score 1):

@user405662 Here's a simplified tree diagram of the "Peter" example that you mentioned in comments. Note that there are two clauses: the sentence as a whole and the embedded subordinate *that* clause. I said "simplified" because the expression "been cheated" is also a subordinate clause functioning as complement of "had", and "cheated" is a subordinate clause functioning as complement of "been". But the principle is the same.

[image]

Pred = predicator (verb)

Comment: I don't know how to thank you for your painstaking efforts!! That really helped, Sir! @BillJ. Just this bit that remains to be cleared— You said _Peter said_ isn't a clause in itself, but rather part of one. If I were to write instead _Peter is said to have been cheated_, there is the matrix clause (the entire sentence) and the subordinate non-finite clause _to have been cheated_, right? The mere presence of a verb (*said* here and in _Peter said_) alone doesn't suffice to call part of a sentence a clause. There is one matrix clause and rest of the dependent clauses are _non-finite clauses._

Comment: Continued: There is one matrix clause and rest of the dependent clause/clauses are either non-finite or they could be finite too. Like in this— _Peter, who had been cheated, was distraught._ Matrix clause (the entire sentence) and the dependent  finite clauses _who had been cheated_ and _was crying._ Is that right?

Comment: @user405662 The first sub clause is "said to have been cheated" (comp of matrix verb "is"), and within that clause is the sub clause "to have been cheated" (comp of "said") Within that clause is the further sub clause "been cheated" (comp of "have") and finally within that clause is the sub clause "cheated" (comp of "been"). There are 5 verbs and thus 5 clauses, one main/matrix, and four subordinate.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much. I will have to revise this post till it firmly sticks in my mind.

Comment: @user405662 In your example  "Peter, who had been cheated, was distraught", the whole sentence is the main/matrix clause. The relative clause "who had been cheated" is subordinate. Then we have the further sub clause "been cheated" (comp of "had"), followed by the sub clause "cheated" (comp of "been"), so 4 verbs altogether and thus 4 clauses, one main/matrix and 3 subordinate.

Comment: Got it. _was crying_ clause is the complement of _Peter_, no?

Comment: @user405662 Sorry, I can't see "was crying" in any of your examples??

Comment: _was distraught_ I meant. Sorry. I had initially used _crying_ in the example and later changed it to _distraught._

Comment: @user405662 In your example "Peter, who had been cheated, was distraught", the clause "who had been cheated" is a supplement. It is subordinate but it's not part of the matrix clause predicate, which is just "was distraught".

Answer (score 0):

> [His family and professional life have made him uniquely able to write
> novels with a family setting]**(A)** [which can absorb the conflict
> between past and present, tradition and novelty, good and evil, common
> beliefs and the idea of the modern family today]**(B)**.

(A) - main clause

(B) - relative (or adjective) clause (A relative clause is a clause that is attached to an antecedent by a relative pronoun such as ***who***, ***which***, or ***that***. In our case B is attached to "a family setting" by "which").

So, yes, you the subordinate clause is the one you found..

Comment: OP has mentioned _adjective clause_ in the question and you have marked the clause as _relative._ That calls for some clarification, right?

Comment: True, thank you for pointing it out. Will edit.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was also thinking that maybe the “to write novels with a family setting” clause could also be a noun clause functioning as adjective complement of “able”. Would that also be correct?

Comment: It is a prepositional phrase and yes it functions as an adjective complement of “able”. Check [this link](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/adjective-complement-examples.html) for more.

Comment: Thank you so much! However, I am still a bit confused. I see it as another subordinate clause in my head but I am not 100% sure (based on the link you sent.) In the sentence: “I am sorry to hear it” our teacher told us that “to heart it” is a non-finite subordinate clause. That’s why am I having trouble understanding the difference

Comment: A subordinate clause will have a subject and a predicate. A prepositional phrase will not have that. In "Are you excited to go to France next year?", **to go to France next year** is a prepositional phrase.

Comment: In the simplest analysis, there is one main clause (the sentence as a whole) and two subordinate clauses, i.e. the infinitival “to write …” clause, and the relative clause “which can absorb …”

Comment: Ok, then [this site](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/adjective-complement-examples.html) is wrong.

Comment: See also this explanation from [freedictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Adjective-Complements.htm): _“I’m very happy to know you!” (To know you is the complement of the adjective happy.)_

Comment: You're mixing up category and function. "To know you" is  a subordinate infinitival clause functioning as complement of "happy". And of course all non-finite clauses are subordinate.

Comment: So in that case, I am right. So“ to write novels with a family setting” in the above mentioned sentence is yet another subordinate clause (non-finite clause), is that correct?

Comment: @Jananlov Yes, infinitival clauses are non-finite, and non-finite clauses are always subordinate.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it!♥️ @BillJ

Comment: Yes, @BillJ, thank you, it is a bit clearer to me how this sentence works according to English grammar standards. I don't understand why available resources are contradictory though...

Comment: The rule is that for every verb (including the auxiliaries) there is a clause. If you apply that rule, you won't go far wrong.

Comment: If we count the verbs: "have" + "made" + "write" + "can" + "absorb", = 5 verbs, so 5 clauses altogether.

Comment: @fev— I think it would be better to call _to go to France next year_ in your example as an infinitive clause within which is embedded the prepositional phrase _to France next year._

Comment: @user405662: Yes, I understood that from BillJ's comments and answer.